# Worst case Big O runtime of the following method

Tags: java, runtime, big-o

```
public static void checkout(int n) {
System.out.println(n);
if (n >= 10) {
  checkout(n/10);
  System.out.println(n);
}
```

I believe the worst case runtime is O(n) but am not sure.

Comment: you probably mean O(log(n))

Comment: Try to be a little more specific about your problem, and try to follow the StackOverflow question guidelines https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

Nir Alfasi is correct - O(log(n)): your amount of data is decreasing by a factor of 10 each iteration through the loop